# Ionic 2 binary file has different content after download

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using the ionic 2 framework and the cordova file plugin.

I am downloading a pdf file from a server, using the php `readfile($path)` method, on the client side, i am using Http from angular/http.
Now the problem is, that after the download and a save using the `writeFile(path, file,data,options)` method from ionic-native/file, the content of the file is not the same as the content from the server.

**Notice: Left the output file and right the server version, both printed with the cat command**.
[image]

I have no idea why the content is not the same.

The http call:

```
    this.http.post(httpEndpoint + ":8280/download", data, headers).subscribe(response => {
  me.proceedFile(response.text(), file, fileManager, opener);

});
```

Here the save:

```
private proceedFile(data:string, file:File, fileManager:FileManger, 
  opener:FileOpener) {

  ...
  const me = this;
  const putFile = function () {

  fileManager.writeFile(fileManager.dataDirectory ,"data/" + 
    strid+"/" + file.name, data, true).then(_ => {

    });

  };
...
}
```

Regards Liz3